# Moving a project to Maven Central

Tags: maven, sonatype

I manage many maven projects.  Most of them deploy to our internal maven repository.  Now I would like to start releasing one project to Maven Central.  Up until now, I have had a parent POM that specified the distributionManagement of our internal repository.  It doesn't make sense to deploy this information to Maven Central.

How should I specify the distribution management for my internal projects?  Should I have a seperate parent pom group-internal for internal projects?

Sonatype mentions a way to deploy directly to their repositories, but they recommend using their own parent pom (oss-parent).  Looking at projects using mvnrepository.org, I couldn't find any projects with oss-parent as the parent.  Do most project manually deploy their artifacts to Sonatype?  Where and how do they deploy them first?

So many questions!  I'm amazed at how complicates this is...

Update: it turns out some of the projects I identified *do* use oss-parent.  It's just hidden as it's the parent of a parent.

Comment: Last time I read about it, I believe you had to raise a ticket with them to get your jar into Maven Central. But you are correct about the Sonatype OSS repository, I think provided you satisfy certain prerequisites they allow you to directly deploy it to their repo. If you are putting some library in the public domain, it should ideally have Apache 2 or similar license. Are you ready to open your code to the world? If you are, it may well make sense to host your code at some place like, Github, SourceForge or Google Code.

Comment: The code is open to the world.  I'm now trying to make the binaries available to the world.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once you are all set up, you can deploy [staged releases](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide#SonatypeOSSMavenRepositoryUsageGuide-7a.3.StageaRelease) and [SNAPSHOTs](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide#SonatypeOSSMavenRepositoryUsageGuide-7a.2.PublishSnapshots) directly to Sonatype's OSS repository.  Stages releases can then be [released through Sonatype's Nexus UI](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide#SonatypeOSSMavenRepositoryUsageGuide-8.ReleaseIt).

To create a repository folder for your application to which you can deploy, you [open a ticket with Sonatype on their JIRA](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide#SonatypeOSSMavenRepositoryUsageGuide-3.CreateaJIRAticket) along with a reference to the open-source project you will deploy.  The process is very smooth and Sonatype will help you if you don't supply all the necessary information.

While on first glace it doesn't look like many projects have oss-parent as a parent, they often do when you navigate up the POM tree.  For example, Google Guava has the parent `guava-parent`, which has the parent `oss-parent`.  Once your project has `oss-parent` and the repository is configured, you can easily deploy SNAPSHOTs and releases with `mvn deploy` or `mvn release:prepare release:perform`.

It seems overwhelming, but it's easily understood if you just plow through the steps for the first time.

Answer (score 6):

The first I recommend to read is the following: 
https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide
The OSS parent makes under special circumstance sense under other not. That depends what kind of project you like to distribute.

**UPDATE**: That link is dead now. Look [here](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/ossrh-guide.html) for help deploying to Sonatype.

**UPDATE**: For Maven Central check this: http://central.sonatype.org/

Comment: I have read that document.  Care to elaborate when the OSS parent makes sense and when it does not?  How do projects without an OSS parent deploy to maven central?  How do they deploy internally with no distributionManagement in their pom.xml?

Comment: Just simply create their own distributionManagement area (http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|com.soebes.smpp|smpp|0.3|pom). You can't deploy internally without an distributionManagement...the best is to have repo manager internally too...If you have a project which is used internally but will be deployed to maven central than this project needs it's own distributionManagement area may by using a different parent but be careful nothing which will gone to maven central should depend on things which are not in maven central.

Comment: The document you refer to has magically disappeared, without any clear successor it seems.

Comment: @MikeBraun looks like the information is now [here](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/ossrh-guide.html).